# AWS IAM Policy to allow Role deletion actions only on resources with specific tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-iam

I am creating a CrossAccount Role to be distributed across multiple AWS Accounts. The goal is to allow one of my lambda to assume this CrossAccount Role and create CFN stacks in the target accounts.

In order to allow the stacks to be deleted, I need to assign actions like **ec2:TerminateInstances** to the role. But I do not want to allow the action on all resources "*". How can I only allow this action on resource with a specific tag?

I tried with following policy condition, but it does not work. When try to delete the stack, I got unauthorized error on **ec2:TerminateInstances** action.

```
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "ec2:TerminateInstances"
  Resource: "*"
  Condition:
    StringEquals:
      aws:RequestTag/Usage: TestOnlyTag
```

Am I on the right track?

Please note, this role needs to be deployed into the target accounts before the stack even created. So there is no way to specified the Instance-Id here.

Comment: Did you try it? Does it work?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I should use **ResourceTag** instead of **RequestTag**. Below are the difference between those 2 according to AWS Documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html

> Resource – Control access to AWS service resources based on the tags
>   on those resources. To do this, use the ResourceTag/key-name condition
>   key to determine whether to allow access to the resource based on the
>   tags that are attached to the resource.
>
> Request – Control what tags can be passed in a request. To do this,
>   use the aws:RequestTag/key-name condition key to specify what tag
>   key-value pairs can be passed in a request to tag or untag an AWS
>   resource.

Below are the working policy.

```
- Effect: "Allow"
  Action:
    - "ec2:TerminateInstances"
  Resource: "*"
  Condition:
    StringEquals:
      aws:ResourceTag/Usage: "TestOnlyTag"
```